# Python dictionary to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, python, object, dictionary

I want to find how many times a character is given in string.

Python codes works

```
def func(a):
d={}
for ch in a:
    if ch in d:
        d[ch] += 1
    else:
        d[ch] = 1
print d
```

and javascript

```js
function how_many_times(string) {
  object = {};
  for (var i in string) {
    if (i in object) {
      object[i] += 1
    } else {
      object[i] = 1
    }
  }
  
  console.log(object)
}

how_many_times('Hello, World !')
```

When I try to pass this to javascript, I don't get the same result. I tried like this because I read python dictionary and javascript object are very similar. I know I can solve problem with other ways but **I want to learn why it doesn't work in objects**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead of [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for the iteration.

The `for ... in` statement iterates over the keys of an object. The final result is an object with all indices and the count of one instead of getting the character and the count of it.

A possible workaround without `in` could be the use of the index as accessor for the wanted value, like `string[i]`.

```js
function how_many_times(string) {
    var object = {},
        i;

    for (i of string) {
        if (i in object) {
            object[i] += 1;
        } else {
            object[i] = 1;
        }
    }
    console.log(object)
}

how_many_times('Hello, World !')
```